# Is it possible in C++ to make an instance of a class as a member of structure?

Tags: c++

```
struct Frame {
  int frame_num;
  BoundingBox bbox;
};
```

In this above structure, `BoundingBox` is a class and later used in the following way. What is the benefit of making a class instance as a member of a structure?

Comment: Why downvote? it looks legit.

Comment: @TomerW ***Lack of research.*** You can't guess your way through `C++` by asking people on the internet. The basics of the language are covered in books or tutorials, this site isn't  really intended to teach people from scratch. Furthermore, the OP simply needed to test the code for themselves.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible in C++ to make an instance of a class as a member of structure?

You've answered your own question in your snippet. Yes, possible.

> what is the benefit of making a class instance as a member of a structure?

What is the benefit of `int frame_num` in `Frame`?  It's the same benefit you get in having custom types.

Classes are a way of making custom types (`BoundingBox` in your example) which work besides the built-in types (`int`, `float`, etc.) the language gives out of the box.  Both can be put inside another custom type (like `Frame`) and they provide a way to interact with data. E.g. `int` is a type that allows the programmer to work with integer data in a specified way i.e. `int` dictates how the values of its type interact with say `float`. Likewise, a custom type will allow the user of the type to work with some data is some fashion.

**Aside**: Classes and structs are *almost* the same in C++.

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine. Go ahead and use it.

The two abstractions -- `Frame` and `BoundingBox` -- server their own purposes. Whether one is a `class` and the other is a `struct` does not change that.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, structures are almost identical to classes.

However, members of a struct are declared as `public` by default, while members of a class are declared as `private` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? A struct is a class so there is nothing special about them.
It's called "Object Association", and it depends on the design. Typically, object association is called the "Has-A" relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ Class and Struct are the Same thing, with minor difference of the default access modifier being **private** for **class** and **public** for **structs**

Additionally, syntax speaking nesting those constructs is allowed if not required inorder to get correct OOP design.

That said, I'd note that, semantically, there is a difference:
as **structs** are mostly used to describe **data**,
while **classes** mostly describe **object**.

Some programmers might (allow themselves to) use `memset` on a struct, or copy it to another memory location.
These operations might corrupt the class like struct by:
- corrupting `vptr` of the contained class member
- If this struct has a virtual method itself then it's own `vptr`.
- Copy pointers and create some surprising results.

Bottom Line:
Nest classes in classes, structs in classes...
But avoid nesting class in struct, there is no good reason to do so.

Also, You might want to embrace the convention of "struct -> DATA, class -> Object"